# Flurry integration into same app on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, analytics, flurry

I have one app that is available on the Android store and the Apple store. I want to integrate Flurry analytics into them. On the Flurry management site, I do not have the option to create 1 application that targets Android AND iOS together.

Can I just get both Flurry SDKs and use the same API key in my code so that both the Android and iOS versions log to the same profile even though the profile is set up to target iOS?

Comment: For 2016, note that the new back end of Flurry conveniently indeed allows you to show both apps at once. That's great, so, there's perhaps little reason to use the same ID.  Importantly, Björn below has proved you can use the same ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've done two Flurry Analytics trials and it works fine.

We created a Flurry iOS project and logged to it with separate iOS & Android apps. We created a Flurry Android project and logged to it with separate iOS & Android apps. 
In both cases actual devices were used.

- Sessions, active users work
- Versions are reported as the same
- Audience | Language is reported as the same
- Custom events are reported as the same internal Flurry ID:s
- Technical web views for device models & firmware versions show both iOS & Android entries.

Flurry Crash Analytics would probably be an issue, for example only one desym file. But we can't use Flurry Crash Analytics for iOS anyway, so as long as the Flurry project is an Android project it should be ok.

The only drawback is that it is not officially supported by Flurry.

Comment: thanks for the real information there, @BjörnWennerström , good one

Answer (score 3):

Although I've never done that and I'm not sure if it can be done because Flurry wants you to specify a platform when you are setting up your app I would say its the wrong idea. I would just create two apps on flurry and keep them unique. In fact I personally create two apps for my iOS apps that are universal and just register a different flurry key if the same app is started on an iPad vs an iPhone. You may miss out on important device information if you try to combine them.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create 2 different apps at flurry for this purpose.